# how do you generate citibike station feed in real-time?

Tags: java, python, json, real-time

I found that the citibike station feed (in json format) updates the data every minute, and I was wondering if there is the way to get those data automatically. Is there any library or framework that I can look upon? If there is a framework that handles this (preferably Java or Python), that would be great.

Comment: json or Rest is passive. So you must reread the file in a short interval. The you can parse the file with an son api like 
https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Comment: @DenisKohl JSON is neither active nor passive, it's just a serialization format. Also, Python includes a json parser, no need to import external modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the JSON data is available as point-in-time snapshots via an http GET. Perhaps you could do something like this to get a snapshot every n seconds:

```
import urllib2
import json
import time

while True:
    citibikenycJson = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.citibikenyc.com/stations/json').read())
    # do something with the JSON
    time.sleep(5)
```